# Transfer Work Item between Work Queues

Tags: c#, filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine

I'm working with FileNET of IBM and I have a question, that is: I want to transfer a work item (or more) from one work queue to another diferent. Is that possible?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that a particular work item can only exists in one queue.  Once you move to the next queue, a new work item is created.

Can you provide more details about the problem you're trying to solve?  Maybe there is a better pattern that can be used to solve it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Tom Puri is correct. You cannot move work items between queues in an ad-hoc fashion. You can "assign" work items to individuals within the same queue but I don't think that is your intent.

You will need to review your workflow design. If this is something that you really need to do then I suggest applying a particular process design pattern such as state-change or star model to your workflow design. This will allow you to dispatch work items to other queues (or the same queue with a different state) quite easily.